# Recursive definition of infinite sequence in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm experimenting with the Kotlin sequences and particular the more complicated ones that are not simple calculations on the previous value.

One example I'd like to define is a sequence of all prime numbers.

An easy way to define the next prime is the next integer that is not divisible by any of the previous primes in the sequence.

In Scala this can be translated to:

```
def primeStream(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = s.head #:: primeStream(s.tail filter(_ % s.head != 0))
val primes = primeStream(Stream.from(2))

// first 20 primes
primes.take(20).toList
```

I'm having trouble translating this to Kotlin. In scala it works because you can pass function that returns a sequence that will be lazily evaluated but I can't do the same in Kotlin.

In Kotlin I tried

```
fun primes(seq: Sequence<Int>):Sequence<Int> = sequenceOf(seq.first()) + primes(seq.drop(1).filter {it % seq.first() != 0})
val primes = primes(sequence(2) {it + 1})

primes.take(20).toList()
```

But that obviously doesn't work because the function is evaluated straight away and leads to an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key point here is to implement a `Sequence` transformation so that its first item remains and the tail is *lazily* transformed from the original `Sequence` tail to something else. That is, the transformation is done only when the item is requested.

First, let's implement lazy sequence concatenation, which behaves like simple concatenation but the right operand is evaluated lazily:

```
public infix fun <T> Sequence<T>.lazyPlus(otherGenerator: () -> Sequence<T>) =
        object : Sequence<T> {
            private val thisIterator: Iterator<T> by lazy { this@lazyPlus.iterator() }
            private val otherIterator: Iterator<T> by lazy { otherGenerator().iterator() }

            override fun iterator() = object : Iterator<T> {
                override fun next(): T =
                        if (thisIterator.hasNext())
                            thisIterator.next()
                        else
                            otherIterator.next()

                override fun hasNext(): Boolean =
                        thisIterator.hasNext() || otherIterator.hasNext()
            }
        }
```

Laziness of `otherIterator` does all the trick: `otherGenerator` will be called only when `otherIterator` is accessed, that is, when the first sequence finishes.

Now, let's write a recursive variant of the sieve of Eratosthenes:

```
fun primesFilter(from: Sequence<Int>): Sequence<Int> = from.iterator().let {
        val current = it.next()
        sequenceOf(current) lazyPlus {
            primesFilter(it.asSequence().filter { it % current != 0 })
        }
    }
```

Note that `lazyPlus` allowed us to lazily make another recursive call of `primesFilter` in the tail of the sequence.

After that, the whole sequence of primes can be expressed as

```
fun primes(): Sequence<Int> {
    fun primesFilter(from: Sequence<Int>): Sequence<Int> = from.iterator().let {
        val current = it.next()
        sequenceOf(current) lazyPlus {
            primesFilter(it.asSequence().filter { it % current != 0 })
        }
    }
    return primesFilter((2..Int.MAX_VALUE).asSequence())
}
```

---

Though this approach isn't very fast. Evaluation of 10,000 primes takes a few seconds, however, the 1000th prime is emitted in about 0.1 second.

Comment: Nice. I wonder why [`Sequence<T>.plus(Sequence<T>)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/kotlin.-sequence/plus.html) isn't lazy like you've implemented `lazyPlus`...

Comment: Well, `Sequence<T>.plus(...)` is just not lazy enough. :) Items of the resulting `Sequence<T>` are evaluated lazily, but the `Sequence<T>` object in right operand is evaluated eagerly, which we need to avoid here as it would lead to `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: This is great as a common library function. It works fast for me. Are you able to explain the need to convert the sequence to an iterator and back again in the implementation of the primesFilter? It seems like a bit of a gotcha if you don't do it then I think the lazy evaluation doesn't work. Is there any possibility to not require this?

Comment: @LionelPort, also, I've been playing around with sequences recently and you can see my related [question & answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114716/how-to-modify-a-prefix-of-a-kotlin-sequence-but-retain-the-tail). The `Iterator` trick is needed to pass the actual sequence's tail into the lazy right operand. It is achieved by passing around the `Iterator` instead of `Sequence`: that would create a new `Iterator` each time which in turn would start the sequence over.

Comment: @LionelPort UPD: however, I was able to rewrite it without the iterator (using `first()` and `drop(1)`), but it works drastically slower, here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/h0tk3y/9192f6246b6c05ccd1b5).

Comment: @hotkey Accepting this as it gives a good general purpose utility method. I actually like your gist better and I might be doing it wrong but I'm not seeing any performance difference in my simple tests.

Comment: @LionelPort, seems strange because for 1000 primes I have: version in answer - 0.1s, version in gist - 4.0s. Here's also a [gist](https://gist.github.com/h0tk3y/6dda2b292d8804d72967) with the iterator trick.

Comment: @hotkey Yep, I had a problem with my test case. The iterator approach is significantly faster.

Comment: Is there a way to speed up `primesFilter` using `tailrec`?

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/09/whats-new-in-standard-library-m13-and-m14/ - This blog post seems to indicate that the default plus operator on sequences (as defined in the stdlib) performs lazy concatenation. Was this feature changed?

Answer (score 4):

You can place the `Sequence<Int>` concatenation inside of a `Sequence<Sequence<Int>>` generator and then flatten it to a `Sequence<Int>` again:

```kotlin
fun primes(seq: Sequence<Int>): Sequence<Int> = sequence {
    seq.take(1) + primes(seq.drop(1).filter { it % seq.first() != 0 })
}.flatMap { it }
val primes = primes(sequence(2) { it + 1 })
```

Output: `[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71]`

It seems a bit slow though. What you probably want is to cache each result in a list and build off of it instead of recalculating the primes recursively. e.g.:

```kotlin
fun primes() = with(arrayListOf(2, 3)) {
    asSequence() + sequence(last() + 2) { it + 2 }
            .filter { all { prime -> it % prime != 0 } }
            .map { it.apply { add(it) } }
}
```

Comment: I really like the idea but it is very slow to generate and the resulting sequence can only be consumed once. The scala version can give me the 1000th prime in under a second so that would be what I'd expect to achieve. +1 for the idea though

Comment: @LionelPort agreed. I've added a caching example that can be consumed more than once. It generated the first 1000 primes for me in ~50 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

My current answer is not to use a recursive function. I can get still get an infinite sequence of primes by modelling the sequence as a pair of values with the first the prime number and the second the current filtered sequence. I then apply the map to only select the first element.

```
val primes = sequence(2 to sequence(3) {it + 2}) {
    val currSeq = it.second
    val nextPrime = currSeq.first()
    nextPrime to currSeq.filter { it % nextPrime != 0}
}.map {it.first}
```

Comment: FYI: That solution doesn't currently work: `[2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67]` is not `[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71]`.

Comment: @mfulton26 Thanks, I see I missed filtering multiples of 2 by starting the sequence at 3. Updated with your fix.